# When should I use input redirection?

Tags: io-redirection

I used the following two commands to produce the same results:-

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep line comments
The line should start with a single quote to comment in VB scripting.
Double slashes in the beginning of the line for single line comment in C.
[root@localhost ~]#

[root@localhost ~]# grep line <comments
The line should start with a single quote to comment in VB scripting.
Double slashes in the beginning of the line for single line comment in C.
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Could any please explain to me any pros/cons if any of these 2 approaches over each other.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the `man grep` page (on Debian):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
>    named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines
>    containing  a  match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the
>    matching lines.
> ```

In the first case, `grep` opens the file; in the second, the shell opens the file and assigns it to the standard input of `grep`, and `grep` not being passed any file name argument assumes it needs to grep its standard input.

### Pros of 1:

- `grep` can grep more than one file¹.
- `grep` can display the file name where each occurrence of `line` is found.
- `grep` could² (but I don't know of any implementation that does) do a `fadvise(POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL)` on the file descriptors it opens.

### Pros of 2:

- If the file can't be opened, the shell returns an error which will include more relevant information (like line number in the script) and in a more consistent way (if you let the shell open files for other commands as well) than when `grep` opens it. And if the file can't be opened, `grep` is not even called (which for some commands -- maybe not `grep` -- can make a big difference).
- in `grep line < in > out`, if `in` can't be opened, `out` won't be created or truncated.
- There's no problem with some files with unusual names (like `-` or file names starting with `-`)³.
- cosmetic: you can put `<file` anywhere on the command-line to show the command flow more naturally, like `<in grep line >out` if you prefer.
- cosmetic: with GNU `grep`, you can choose what label to use in front of the matching line instead of just the file name as in:

  ```
   <file grep --label='Found in file at line' -Hn line
  ```

In terms of performance, if the file can't be opened, you save the execution of `grep` when using redirection, but otherwise for `grep` I don't expect much difference.

With redirection, you save having to pass an extra argument to `grep`, you make `grep`'s argument parsing slightly easier. On the other hand, the shell will need (at least) an extra system call to `dup2()` the file descriptor onto file descriptor 0.

In `{ grep -m1 line; next command; } < file`, `grep` (here GNU `grep`) will want to `seek()` back to just after the matching line so the `next command` sees the rest of the file (it will also need to determine whether the file is seekable or not). In other words, the position within stdin is another one of `grep`'s output. With `grep -m1 line file`, it can optimise that out, that's one fewer thing for `grep` to care about.

---

#### Notes

¹ With `zsh`, you can do:

```
grep line < file1 < file2
```

but that's doing the equivalent of `cat file1 file2 | grep line` (without invoking the `cat` utility) and so is less efficient, can cause confusion if the first file doesn't end in a newline character and won't let you know in which file the pattern is found.

² That is to tell the system that `grep` is going to read the file sequentially so the I/O scheduler can make more educated decisions for instance as to how to read the data. `grep` can do that on its *own* fd, but it would be wrong to do it on that fd 0 that it *borrows* from its caller, as that fd (or rather the *open file description* it references) could be used later or even at the same time for non-sequential read. In practice though, you'll notice that GNU `sort` still does just that.

³ In the case of `ksh93` and `bash` though, there are files like  `/dev/tcp/host/port` (and `/dev/fd/x` on some systems in `bash`) which, when used in the target of redirections the shell intercepts for special purposes instead of really opening the file on the file system (though generally, those files don't exist on the file system). `/dev/stdin` serves the same purpose as `-` recognised by `grep`, but at least, here it's more properly namespaced (anybody can create a file called `-` in any directory, while only administrators can create a file called `/dev/tcp/host/port` and administrators should know better).

Comment: +1, for the nice explanation. I have one doubt: in the 2nd case when the shell opens the file does it pass the opened file contents to the standard input (keyboard) ?? ( I got confused with the term 'standard input of grep').

Comment: @Ankit, stdin is where applications read their input by default, the file descriptor 0. When in a terminal, fd 0 is opened from reading on the terminal device (something like /dev/ttyxx or /dev/pts/n). That's how they end up getting what you type on the keyboard. Shell redirection of a command's stdin just opens the fd 0 to some other file before executing the command.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by StephaneChazelas covers `grep(1)`, and most Unix lineage commands work that way, but not all. It is standard to read either from standard input
(from the keyboard, from a file redirected via `< file`, or from the output piped by another command, stupid example `ls * | grep '^ab*c$'`), or from the file(s) given as arguments, like `grep comment file1 file2 file3`. Some commands use the convention there that the file named `-` is standard input, so you can say `make-middle | cat head - tail` to get a stream with `head`, whatever `gen-middle` generates, followed by `tail`. This is by design, to give flexibility in the use of the commands.

Which is better? As long as it works, `cmd file` is shorter than `cmd < file`; there could be a *tiny* difference in time between the shell doing the file frobbing (`<`) and the command doing it by itself, but probably unnoticeable unless you do nothing else all day long. It will depend on considerations like the pros mentioned in Stephane's answer.

Comment: `cmd file` is not shorter than `cmd<file` though.

Comment: It's one _keystroke_ shorter though, presuming you need to press Shift in order to type a `<`.