# sed command to find lines which are not of specific size

Tags: sed

I have this file, I want to print all the lines that are not of size 21.

```
PASY$ type a.a
000008050110010201NNN
000008060810010201NNN
21212000008070110010201NNN
000008080310010201NNN
000008090510010201NNN
000008050110010201NNN
000008060310010201NNN
00008070110010201NNN
```

Comment: you mean the number of char in Line.

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear" rather than "duplicate" because the OP was "refining" the question in comments below to ask for completely different things from those asked for above.

Comment: Appears they’ve asked a second question, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '/^.\{21\}$/d;q' input-file
```

`sed` will `d`elete (and therefore not print) the first line with precisely 21 characters between the beginning and end of the line (the actual file will not be modified despite the use of scary words like "delete").  If such a line is found, it immediately will stop processing further lines.

Comment: DopeGhoti how can i get out of the sed one a single sed matching record is found . in my case as soon as a record that is not of size 21 is found i want to report and exit sed.

Comment: By using the `q` command as I will shortly illustrate in an edit to my answer.

Comment: @AhmadS Your question asks specifically to _print all lines_ that are not 21 characters long. You are changing the question as you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^.....................$/!p' < input-file
```

If there are not 21 characters between the beginning (`^`) of the line and the end (`$`) of the line, print it.

More positively, `d`elete lines that *are* 21 characters long (printing other lines by default):

```
sed '/^.....................$/d' < input-file
```

Comment: Why `sed 'stuff' < file` rather than just `sed 'stuff' file`?

Comment: Took me a minute to track it back down, but I've started leaning towards that habit after reading [this answer from Stéphane on input redirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/117549). It's also a small visual reminder that we're not attempting to *edit* the file (which `sed -i` or other utilities might do).

Comment: Interesting read, but I'd probably end up leaning the other way so that I don't end up trying to `tool args < file1 file2` which won't work unless the tool in question is really smart about handling _both_ stdin _and_ file arguments at the same time.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i wanted .  but can i get out of sed  at the very first not match ? i dont want it scanning the whole file .

Comment: You should edit the question (ideally, when initially asking it) to clarify that requirement. Most simply, tack on a ... `| head -1`

Comment: Or `sed '/re/p;q' file`.

Comment: @AhmadS You have to scan the whole file if you want to print all lines that are not 21 characters.