# report if any one record is not of matching size using sed

Tags: sed

how can I use `sed` to report any first record that is not of size 21 in a file?

I don't want `sed` to scan the complete file and get out as soon as the first record which is not of size 21 is found.

Comment: i have the sed command i am not sure how to break out of it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed command to find lines which are not of specific size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444204/sed-command-to-find-lines-which-are-not-of-specific-size)

Comment: In fairness, this is a duplicate of what the other question was apparently _meant_ to be as opposed to what the other question is _stated_ to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444209/65304)

```
sed -n '/^.\{21\}$/! {p;q;}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` (this would be easiest):

```
awk 'length != 21 { printf("Line of length %d found\n", length); exit }' file
```

Or, as part of a shell script,

```
if ! awk 'length != 21 { exit 1 }' file; then
    echo 'Line of length != 21 found (or awk failed to execute properly)'
else
    echo 'All lines are 21 characters (or the file is empty)'
fi
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
sed -nE '/^.{21}$/!{p;q;}' file
```

With GNU `sed`, you would be able to do

```
if ! sed -nE '/.{21}$/!q 1' file; then
   echo 'Line with != 21 characters found (or sed failed to run properly)'
else
   echo 'All lines are 21 characters (or file is empty)'
fi
```

Comment: using sed please

Comment: @AhmadS See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`:

```
if line=$(grep -Exnvm1 '.{21}' < file); then
  printf >&2 'Found "%s" which is not 21 characters long\n' "$line"
fi
```

(`-n` above includes the line number)